# MySQL query timing out: (70100): Query execution was interrupted

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to execute a MySQL query in order to delete all `Wp_posts` table rows which `post_parent` is a `Wp_posts` row with `post_type` set to product;

So I do

```
INSERT INTO temp (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "product")
```

(Inserts 4k rows)

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent IN (SELECT tid FROM temp)
```

..

After around 100 seconds, it returns

> ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted

What could be making this query so bloody slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of MySQL implement `in` with a subquery in a very inefficient manner.  Change it to a correlated `exists` clause:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
    WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM temp where temp.tid = wp_posts.post_parent)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need change your `max_allowed_packet` to a higher value in your `my.ini` configuration file.

This might help:

> #### [Packet Too Large](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)
>
> A communication packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a master replication server to a slave.
>
> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL 5.5 server or client is 1GB.

Comment: A link to the documentation *always* make an Answer better. A brief summary is a plus too ;)

Comment: Thanks. I think this might help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html