# PDO over network, hangs MySql Database after running 1 to 3 hours?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, networking, pdo

I have the following class

```
--------------------------------------------- CRUD Code Snippet--------------------
class CRUD{
    function __construct(){
    $this->db_user = "user_name";
    $this->db_pass = "user_password";
    $this->db_name = "myDb";
    $this->host = "localhost";
    }       


//connect() function to connect to database
private function connect(){
    try{
        $pdo_Options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db_name};charset=utf8", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $pdo_Options);             
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        return $ex->getMessage();
        $this->tempVar = $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


       ----------- The following method creates problems when updating record --------------
       public function dbQuery($sql,$bindVars=array()){
        try{
            $this->connect();
            $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute($bindVars);
            if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
                }
            else{
                return false;
                }
                $this->con = null;
            }catch(PDOException $exc){
                $this->tempVar = $exc->getMessage();
                $this->sqlToReturn = $sql;
                return false;
                }
        }

   }//CRUD
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The function running very good and it performs its work perfectly but after certain time of execution **MySql** database get hangs and stop responding. The page code where the mentioned **function dbQuery()** called, it shows an error after consuming 120 seconds of time. in my scenario, the software is running over a huge network and having apx: 300 concurrent users who are inserting, updating, searching and deleting records in database. Database having apx: 300000 records. 
I have installed WAMP server on windows 8.1 64-bit. MySql Version is : 5.6.20, on T110-II Power Edge Xeon server machine.

I did not find/diagnosed the issue why this problem occurs?

Please guide me, as I'm really worrying about this problem.
[image]

Comment: provide the error message for better understanding of your problem

Comment: It takes minutes to perform a single page opening. also it fails and sometime it shows the above error and or often it shows that **maximum time limit reach 120 ...**

Comment: your problem in mysql query, please provide it or check it yourself.
take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824486/mysql-query-timing-out-70100-query-execution-was-interrupted) and [this one(Why this interruption will happen?)](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/51380-cdbcommand-failed-to-execute-the-sql-statement/)

Comment: $bindUpdat = array(':sno'=>$caseId);            if($db->dbQuery("Update chronologicallists set isOut = 1 where caseSno = :sno AND isDecided = 1 AND isCurrent = 1",$bindUpdat)){
                             }

Answer (score -2):

This might help you:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);
```

Comment: I think an explanation for OP would be nice!

Comment: Dear Sandesh jadhav, the execution time required to run this query / page is only 0.1 Second. i have already exceeded the same to 3 minutes, but the error occurs when the server got slows?

Comment: @Rizier123 The software running good and very fast in first time till to 1 to 2 hours but in the meanwhile it got slows and not performing and then throws an error.