# Mysql error 1317 sqlstate 70100 but why?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So recently i got a Mysql exception `error 1317 sql-state 70100` which i know it means that the query was interrupted but i want learn more about it. Why was it interrupted so that i do something about it and i don't get the same error again.Was it the server overload, was it the size of the data returned (causes that i found through searching about the error code)...what really caused the error?

So this is my question, how can i learn more about the cause of this mysql error ?

Comment: It could be any number of things, but I've found it's usually hit some sort of resource limit. Turn on slow query logging, and use a tool such as Percona Toolkit to help optimize your queries and tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query timing out: (70100): Query execution was interrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824486/mysql-query-timing-out-70100-query-execution-was-interrupted)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just want to have a more specific reason for the interruption. I will try the slow query logging and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error if previously runned "KILL QUERY id"